# How to make a submit button a link to another HTML document after it's validated using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Alright, so I'm trying to make a prototype for a project I'm currently making for college. I'm not very familiar with using any code, so I've just been generally figuring things out as they go.

I'm using html to make a form for users to enter a word.
This is the form in html:

```
<div class="antwoordveld">
    <form  id="form1"  action="opdracht.html" method="post">
        <p><input type="text" name="" value="" placeholder=""></p>
        <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Klaar"></p>
    </form>
</div>
```

The jquery used to check the answer and change the css of the button is this:

```
$("#form1").submit(function( e ) { 
    e.preventDefault();

    if ($("input:first").val().toLowerCase() === "daken") {
        goedantwoord.play();
        $(".submit input").css("background-color", "green");
        $("input:first").val("");
    }
    else {
        foutantwoord.play();
        $(".submit input").css("background-color", "red");
        $("input:first").val("");
    }
});
```

The else statement is what happens if you type in the wrong answer, and the if statement is what happens if you enter the right answer. In both cases it plays a sound, and changes the color of the button.

What I want to do, is when you give the correct answer, the submit button of the form changes to a link (So it sends the person who clicks the submit button after a correct answer gets linked to a different HTML document) and I want to change the text on the submit button.

I've tried to use .replaceWith(), but whenever I changed the html in the form, the entire form broke. The answer to this problem is probably very obvious, but I'm out of ideas at this point.

I hope someone can help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: the user needs to click the button for a second time? Or it just changes the text and redirects them? And if its option 2, does it delay a few seconds before redirecting them so they can see the text?

Comment: The "default" behavior is to redirect to your `action` URL upon submission of the form.  Your `submit()` handler contains `preventDefault()` which "prevents" the "default" behavior from happening.  When you over-ride default behaviors, you need to replace them with your own.